# Insert Values into table of specific row

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am looking to insert some values into a column based on the selection of a specific row. I have a table with columns a, b, c, and d. I want to insert the values 1, 2, and 3 into columns b, c, and d when column `a = X`. I cannot find how to do this.

Toad for oracle is my platform and I am looking for SQL code.

Comment: You want to 'insert' ? Your code doesn't work doing an "update... Where a = x" ?

Comment: You can also give condition to insert queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either update them one at a time:

```
update mytable set b = 1 where a = X;
update mytable set c = 2 where a = X;
update mytable set d = 3 where a = X;
```

Or update them all in one go:

```
update mytable set b = 1,c = 2,d = 3 where a = X;
```

Alternatively, assuming 'a' is a primary key column or unique index and there is only 1 row `where a = X`, if you only have 4 columns and you want to update 3 of them you could delete your row and re-insert the whole lot:

```
delete from mytable where a = X;
insert into mytable values(X, 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: My brain stopped working. Forgot about updates!! Thanks!

Comment: Second way is a wrong way to do that! Consider you have many rows 'WHERE a = x', you delete them all, and then you add only one row.
You should update them all.

Comment: @WhiteHat that's a good point, I made an assumption that 'a' column was the primary key, I have edited the answer to clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT INTO...SELECT` and give condition to your insert queries such as:

```
INSERT
INTO table_name (b, c, d)
VALUES (bValue, cValue, dValue)
/* Select Condition */
WHERE a=1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update mytable set b = 1,c = 2,d = 3 where a = X;
```